# Try Catch in Android native library fails

Tags: android, crash, java-native-interface, try-catch, throw

When I perform a throw command in my native library, my Android application crashes. Does Android not support these calls? It never reaches the catch.

```
try
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "nativeLib", "throw");
    throw;
}
catch (...) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "nativeLib", "catch");
}
```

I recently switched from gnustl_shared to c++_shared, I'm not sure if this has anything to do with my problem.

Developer guides say that gnustl_shared has exceptions enabled by default, but c++_shared does not. I have included the -fexceptions flag as describe in the guide.
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why does throw "nothing" causes program termination?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651154/why-does-throw-nothing-causes-program-termination)

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it fundamentally changes the sense of the question, and of the current answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html

Compatibility

The NDK's libc++ is not stable. Not all the tests pass, and the test suite is not comprehensive. Some known issues are:

•Using c++_shared on ARM can crash when an exception is thrown.

•Support for wchar_t and the locale APIs is limited.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. From the C++ standard:

> If no exception is presently being handled, executing a throw-expression with no operand calls terminate()(15.5.1).

If you want it to catch you need to throw something:

```
try
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "nativeLib", "throw");
    throw new std::exception();
}
catch (...) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "nativeLib", "catch");
    env->ExceptionCheck();
}
```

Comment: The application still crashes on the throw with the addition of new std::exception();

Comment: Can you add the stack to the question?

Comment: stack contains information I cant release. but I am getting A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)

Comment: Try adding env->ExceptionCheck(); to the catch.

Comment: Creating a new project I am able to throw and catch fine. It's almost like exceptions are not supported in my current project. I have -fexception cflag in my make

Comment: Did you try my fix with ExceptionCheck()? I saw the same behavior as yours before I added it. JNI has some funny behavior sometimes....

Comment: I tried with no success, thanks for the attempt though. Would switching from APP_STL := gnustl_shared to APP_STL := c++_shared cause this problem?

Comment: I've created an empty android project to test c++_shared and gnustl_shared. -fexceptions is used in both cases and the only change I make is swapping c++_shared for gnustl_shared. c++_shared crashes on the throw, gnustl_shared executes as expected and does not crash on the throw.

Comment: Documentation for c++_shared states that it supports exceptions, but I am unsuccessful in making this happen. If anyone knows of any other setup requirements for c++_shared or has insight into why exceptions for c++_shared, it would appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Has this severe error been established as a official bug within the Android developer community? If not, it should. It is really a major, major flaw in the design. Catastrophic.